# How to set values in Vuex store in Nuxt.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I have never used `Vuex` with `Nuxt.js`, so I have met the problem. Here is my `store/index.js` file:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  wrongCredentials: false,
  logged: false,
  uxd: null
})

export const mutations = {
  setWrongCredentials(state, value) {
    state.wrongCredentials = value
  },
  setLogged(state, value) {
    state.logged = value
  },
  setUxd(state, value) {
    state.uxd = value
  },
}
```

As you can see there is state and mutations. In my other file, where I check user's JWT token and, depending on resultM I want set values in store:

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import cert from '../jwt/public'

export default {
  verify (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, cert, async (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        this.$store.state.wrongCredentials = true
        this.$store.state.logged = false
        this.$store.state.uxd = null
      } else {
        this.$store.state.wrongCredentials = false
        this.$store.state.logged = true
        this.$store.state.uxd = decoded.uxd
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The code you see doesn't work correctly, it just doesn't set values, so, I have created mutations and did something like this:

`await this.$store.dispatch('setWrongCredentials', true)`

Also doesn't work. The problem is, I don't know how to work with `Vuex` store not in `.vue` files, so, how can I set values in store?

Comment: Where are you invoking this `verify()` function? From a component?

Comment: @tony19 Yes, from my component, to verify token, that user gets after log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have not found solution of this problem like I wanted in `.js` file, so, here is another solution.

First of all, you need to set no only state and mutations, but also actions:

```js
export const actions = {
  fetchWrongCredentials(ctx, value) {
    ctx.commit('setWrongCredentials', value)
  },
  fetchLogged(ctx, value) {
    ctx.commit('setLogged', value)
  },
  fetchUxd(ctx, value) {
    ctx.commit('setUxd', value)
  }
}
```

And in your `Vue` component you need to set values in state using actions, just like that:

```js
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchWrongCredentials', 'fetchLogged', 'fetchUxd']),
    async login() {
      await login({
        password: this.userPassword,
        login: this.userLogin,
        twoFactor: this.twoFactor
      }).then(result => {
        const jwtRes = jwt.verify(result.token)
        this.fetchLogged(true)
        this.fetchWrongCredentials(false)
        this.fetchUxd(jwtRes.token)
      }).catch(() => {
        this.fetchLogged(false)
        this.fetchWrongCredentials(true)
        this.fetchUxd(null)
        this.error = true
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.error = false
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
  }
```

In my case, I had to modify that `.js` file:

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import cert from '../jwt/public'

export default {
  verify (token) {
    return jwt.verify(token, cert, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return false
      } else {
        return { token: decoded.uxd }
      }
    })
  }
}
```